# How to test aiohttp and peewee-async?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-asyncio, peewee, aiohttp

I wanna run 2 asynchronous tests for my database class with aiohttp and peewee-async.

```
@unittest_run_loop
async def test_create_instance(self):
    instance = await self.model.create_instance({})
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(instance, dict))
    self.assertTrue(instance is not None)

@unittest_run_loop
async def test_retrieve_instance(self):
    instance = await self.model.create_instance({})
    retrieved = await self.model.retrieve_instance(int(instance['id']))
    self.assertTrue(instance == retrieved)
```

But I give just

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway
```

Thanks you for your attention!

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the code under test, thanks.

Comment: Also can you point out the line the error occurs on.

Comment: @Denny how did you solve this? have the same issue

Comment: @Kapucko As I remember, I just added explicit close loop in teardown, and init new one and peewee connection  with that loop in setup. You can try to see example in aiohttp docs. Peewee has a trouble with error handling, it can not send new request to database if got error, you need to reconnect to database. I can write you later full code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution I pushed to my repo.
You can watch it here:
https://github.com/dennypenta/aiohttp-peewee

Feed free to star my repo, create issue and ask any questions.

My twitter: @denny_penta